# Failed to obtain schema in self reference check while using openapi generator

Tags: typescript, rest, openapi, openapi-generator

I wrote an openapi specification and now I want to generate a client for it.

[openapi.yaml](https://gitlab.com/metahkg/metahkg-server/-/blob/master/openapi.yaml)

So I went with [openapi generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) and generated a typescript-axios client using this command:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-axios -i openapi.yaml -o src/client
```

However while generating I got a lot of errors, most of them being related to self reference check

```
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `createdAt` in self reference check
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `lastModified` in self reference check
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `lastModified` in self reference check
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `slink` in self reference check
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `slink` in self reference check
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `id` in self reference check
```

Then I checked the generated `src/client`, and it was full of type errors and import errors. e.g.

```
import { Id } from './Id';
```

while there's no Id.ts

I understand it is because of the use of many self-referencing in my spec, but I need them. It is almost possible to have no self-references.

I searched for help but did not find much useful information.

So is it possible that I can somehow fix it or use another tool? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @wcyat. It would be good to post sample here instead of link to repository, since repository can change and it is not straightforward to see original source code

Answer (score 0):

Erros like

```
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to obtain schema from `createdAt` in self reference check
```

means you are using

```
$ref: "#/components/schemas/createdAt
```

but there is no definition of object "createdAt". (just example, createdAt is probably string not object):

```
createdAt:
  type: object
  ...
```

At least this was my case. I just had reference to some old objects that no longer existed.
Also check for typing errors.